# Jquery загрузка страниц

Tags: jquery, html

Добрый день, хочу сделать небольшой статический сайт без перезаргузи основной страницы при переходе по ссылкам. Просто заргужая страны в div блок, пытаюсь все это реализовать через jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('li a').click(function(){  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  
        $('.load-in').fadeOut('fast', loadContent);
         $('.loader').show();

        function loadContent() {  
            $('.load-in').css({ opacity : 0.3 }).load( toLoad , hideLoad );   
        };

        function hideLoad () {
            $('.load-in').fadeIn('fast' ,

            function () { //прячем лоадер и opacity 1
            $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.load-in').animate({ opacity : 1 }); }
            );
        };

    return false; 
    });

});
```

css

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
.ab {width:60px;height:60px;background:red;}
.wrap {width:900px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
.load-in {}
.loader {
height:60px;
width:60px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-30px;
position:fixed;
top:30%;
display:none;
z-index:1000;
background:url('images/preloader.gif') center no-repeat red;
}
```

разметка

```
 <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="wrap">
    <ul>
    <li class="ab"><a href="load.html">load me</a></span>
    <li class="ab"><a href="loader.html">load here</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="load-in">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Но почему-то callback в этой сторчке

```
$('.load-in').css({ opacity : 0.3 }).load( toLoad , hideLoad );
```

Срабатывает до того как загружаются картинки в загружамой странице. Нужно что бы opacity и preloader убирались после того как контент и картинки полность загружены. 
Не особо разбираюсь в jquery, так что если вопрос нубский заранее извиняюсь!

Спасибо!

Comment: после загрузки надо в списке $('.load-in img') искать элементы у которых !element.prop(complete), в род области видимости завести счетчик таких и выставить его по количеству этих элементов, на срабатывание element.load() уменьшать его , когда счетчик достигнет 0 - убирать opacity и preloader.

Comment: а вообще я бы не закладывался на $.load() его судя по текущим тенденциям в jquery могут отменить. как это уже сделали с toggle()

Answer (score 1):

Потому что событие `ready` срабатывает у `document` раньше загрузки изображений. Нужно использовать `$(window).load()` вместо `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Прописал $(window).load(), но почему-то не помогло!
http://cone.hostei.com/index3.html
при переходе preloader и opacity применяются прежде чем контен загружен!

Answer (score 0):

Кму интренесно, решение нашлось через вот актой кусок кода

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('li a').click(function(){  
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');  
        $('.load-in').fadeOut('fast', loadContent);
         $('.loader').show();

        function loadContent() {
    var $loadIn = $('.load-in');

    $loadIn.css({ opacity : 0.3 }).load(toLoad , function () {
        var $images = $('img', $loadIn),
            imageCount = $images.length,
            loadedCount = 0;

            //wait on images before showing the content
            $images.on('load', function () {
                if (++loadedCount === imageCount) {
                    $images.off('load');
                    $('.loader').hide(); 
                    $loadIn.show().animate({ opacity: 1}, 300 );
                }
            });

           //make sure the content is still shown if images fails to load
           //or are very slow to load
           setTimeout(function () {
               if (loadedCount !== imageCount) {
                   $images.off('load');
                   $('.loader').hide(); 
                   $loadIn.show().animate({ opacity: 1}, 300 );
               }
           }, 5000);
    });   
};

        return false; 
    });  
});

</script>
```

css

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}
.ab {width:60px;height:60px;background:red;}
.wrap {width:900px;margin:0 auto;position:relative;}
.load-in {height:500px;width:800px;margin:0 auto;}
.loader {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-30px;
    position:fixed;
    top:30%;
    display:none;
    z-index:1000;
    background:url('images/preloader.gif') center no-repeat;
    }
```

разметка

```
<div class="loader"></div>
<div class="wrap">
<ul>
<li class="ab"><a href="load.html">load me</a></li>
<li class="ab"><a href="loader.html">load here</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="load-in">
</div>

<img src="images/preloader.gif">
</div>
```